# Unable to set df index in freq 10 min

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a timeseries with Pandas(Python). I am traying to set the index freq to 10min.

I create the new_index:

```
new_index = pd.date_range("2022-01-01", periods=7844, freq="10 min")
```

Update my df with the new__index

```
data_df['new_Date']=new_index
```

Set date as index

```
data_df.set_index('new_Date',inplace=True)
```

Then I print the new index freq:

```
print(data_df.index.freq)
```

**Output: None**

I can't figure out why, even though I explicitly create an index with the freq option, once in the `df` it is not recognized.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: sorry, python, Pandas library.